# Help converting a string to number please

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert a string to number and no matter what I do, get strings still.

```
        var lastDigit:Number = Number(e.target.name.charAt(e.target.name.length-1));
            trace ('lastDigit is number = ' + lastDigit is Number)
```

And this traces false. I also tried parseInt and get a type coercion error.

Thanks in advance! I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: have you tried using int or uint instead of Number, just to see if it works?

Comment: Try putting `lastDigit is Number` in parenthesis like `(lastDigit is Number)`. Does that work?

Comment: try with int(e.target.name.charAt(e.target.name.length-1));

Answer (score 2):

this might help:

```
var bool:Boolean = lastDigit is Number;
trace(bool);
trace(lastDigit)
trace(typeof(lastDigit));
```

*trace(...lastDigit is Number)* is false because it is evaluated as a string in the trace statement

Comment: Thanks so very much!! Too funny, my code would have worked had I tried but I psyched myself out thinking I had strings!! Such fun. Ya live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
trace ('lastDigit is number = ' + lastDigit is Number)
```

This is the same as:

```
var lastDigit:Number = 10;
var str:String = 'lastDigit is number = ' + lastDigit;

trace(str is Number);
```

You're checking if `'lastDigit is number = ' + lastDigit` is a number.

If you try,

```
trace(lastDigit is Number);
```

That shall work.

Comment: Thank you very much! tracing 'lastDigit is Number) does trace true.

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

Refer this.

Comment: 1. Why delete and repost after I fix it? 2. This has nothing to do with the question..?

Comment: Is u want to convert last digit as number?

Comment: I don't know... what is your problem... My answer is relevent to your question... Is it or not?

Comment: Sorry bro, didn't mean to sound aggressive. Nice code but it's not the solution to the problem - he's trying to convert a string to a number not find all the numbers in the string.

Comment: @ Mr.Marty Wallace :  I have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets around "lastDigit is Number":

trace ('lastDigit is number = ' + (lastDigit is Number))

which should give you
lastDigit is number = true